# What is the best way to test drf serializer validate

Tags: django, validation, testing, django-rest-framework, serialization

I think two way how can i test drf serializer validate

following is my serializer validate code

```
def validate_md5(self, md5):
    if len(md5) != 40:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Wrong md5")
    return md5
```

and it is test code

1)

```
def test_wrong_validate_md5_2(self):
    url = reverse('apk-list')
    response = self.client.post(url, {'md5':'test'}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

2)

```
def test_wrong_validate_md5(self):
    serializer = ApkSerializer(data=self.apk)

    if len(self.apk.get('md5')) != 40:
        self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), False)
    else:
        self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), True)
```

what is better than another?
or is there best solution?

and ... I practice test-driven coding. is it necessary to write test code as above

Comment: Your way is correct, and don't see any issues in test driven as well, you can check text `Wrong md5` for negative testing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first method actually doesn't test serializer class. It's testing entire `'apk-list'` endpoint. Since error may be raised not only in serializer's `validate_md5` method, but in any other places even if `self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)` will be passed you cannot be sure that serializer worked as expected.
So second method is preferabe. But instead of `if/else` in one test caseyou'd better create two different test case: one for correct data another for incorrect and also you can check if error indead related with md5 field:

```
def test_wrong_validate_md5(self):
    serializer = ApkSerializer(data=self.apk_wrong)
    self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), False)
    self.assertEqual(set(serializer.errors.keys()), set(['md5']))

def test_correct_validate_md5(self):
    serializer = ApkSerializer(data=self.apk_correct)
    self.assertEqual(serializer.is_valid(), True)
```

**UPD**

It's also possible to use first method, but in this case you need to parse response data. And check if this data contains error with 'md5' key, something like:

```
def test_wrong_validate_md5_2(self):
    url = reverse('apk-list')
    response = self.client.post(url, {'md5':'test'}, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    self.assertEqual(response.data,{'md5': Wrong md5')
```

Comment: wow. your explanation is perfect.
and I have more question...
when i write test code, it is too detailed a test...
is it necessary? i don't know if i have to do...

Comment: @HyungWonKim I've added example to show how you can actually test md5_valid with first method. It's up to you which one to use.

Comment: @HyungWonKim Sorry, I dont actually understand you second question.

Comment: I know the test code is important, but it seems to write the test code too detailed. I actually wonder if the serializer is being tested like that.

Comment: @HyungWonKim yes, checking edge cases like in your example is common practice in unittesting.

Comment: Thank you neverwalkaloner! It was a great help